# Can I use this to generate a PHP CRYPT_BLOWFISH salt?

Tags: php, salt, blowfish

I'm basically using this:

```
$chars = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ./';
$numChars = strlen($chars);
$salt = '$2a$12$';

for($i = 0; $i < 22; ++$i) {
    $salt .= $chars[mt_rand(0, $numChars - 1)];
}
```

Is it okay to use that?

Comment: Why not just use [`crypt()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php)?

Comment: I am using `crypt()`, but initially you need to generate a salt for the crypt algorithm you want to use.

Comment: Fair enough. @arxanas, how do you know that?

Comment: @JaredFarrish He's asking how to use the salt for `CRYPT_BLOWFISH`, which is used in `crypt`.

Comment: @arxanas - But that mean he's using `crypt()` (or, `bcrypt`)?

Comment: @JaredFarrish ...yes? http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php explicitly mentions those constants because they're used to signal things about `crypt`.

Answer (score 1):

For PHP version 5.3.7 or higher I belive this is the best:

```
$blowfish_salt = "$2y$10$".bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(22));
```

For PHP version 5.5 or higher just use the new `password_hash()` [function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) with automatic salt creation.

Answer (score 0):

That's good to use. You working too hard on randomizing your salt though.

You could always do something shady like this $salt = md5(mt_rand()) :)

Just use something like this when you want to save the password on your next step.

```
    $encryptedPassword = crypt($userPassword, $salt);
```

This should default to blowfish if you have an up to date version of PHP

Comment: I have PHP 5.3 and it defaults me to MD5 -_-'

Comment: "up to date" is too vague; this is "dangerous". There is no "working too hard".

Comment: @JaredFarrish Yes there is: it's called reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Sorry, up to date means 5.3.7+

Comment: @arxanas - Reread the comment; this is bologne. The PHP Blowfish algorithm has had some problems in certain versions. The whole "point" in password hashing is to make data "recovery" (by rainbow or otherwise brute force methods) as difficult as possible to recover.

Comment: @(arxanas Jared Farrish)  Oh you two, let's not fight. :) Jared do you know a better algorithm than blowfish that is available in php? Or if in those certain versions of PHP will default to the next algorithm?

Comment: I prefer Blowfish [in certain versions, implemented correctly](http://www.php.net/security/crypt_blowfish.php). Other algorithms like SHA_256 and SHA_512 may be "faster" than I like, but in lower versions than 5.3.7, I'd pick those possibly (considering) than BLOWFISH.

Comment: @Jared Farrish Ya, I don't know they are so muuuuch faster, and I absolutely hate that. What is an example of a problem in these certain versions does blowfish create?

Comment: "Fast" algorithms mean databases (for lookups) can be generated "quicker" comparative algorithms. The best attack against most hashed data values right now is simply checking for a matching value in a database; hence, salts, which randomize that data due to "separate" injected values. So. A "fast" algorithm is less "desirable" than a "slow" algorithm, simply because it takes longer to recreate a table to a certain degree and depth. We're talking many, many, many, many thousands of rounds, though. The law of large numbers applies.

Comment: Ya, we understand that. Faster algorithms mean that hackers can brute force quicker, but I was still seeking an example of the certain problems for our friend Ryan using crypt on >= 5.3.7.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether it's okay to use, but since `mt_rand` is based on system time it's predictable.  It'd be better to use a superior random generation algorithm like `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes` or the `/dev/random` utility if it's available.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6337021/454533

Answer (score 0):

With Blowfish you only need 21 chars for the salt the rest is forgotten.

This part `$2a$12$` is not a salt its the algorithm and cost(iterations of hash).

Your salt can be made simply by sha1 and then return the first 21 chars:

`$salt = substr(sha1($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].uniqid().microtime(true)),0,21);`

So something like:

```
$algo = '$2a$12$'; //Keep this safe

//store along side hash as the salt, for future compares
$salt = substr(sha1($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].uniqid().microtime(true)),0,21);

$hash = crypt('The string to be hashed', $algo.$salt.'$');
```

Comment: Heres a [secure login class](https://code.google.com/p/php-pdo-secure-login-script-example/source/browse/branches/index.php) example I made a while back, perhaps its of interest, uses sha512 @ 25k times lol its largely overkill

Comment: Why would using SHA512 more than once make it any more secure? If anything, it should make it more likely for collisions to occur.

Comment: @arxanas its for creating a **slow hash** Imagine that you use a hash function that can only run 1 million times per second on the same hardware, instead of 1 billion times per second. It would then take the attacker 25k times longer to brute force a hash. 60 hours would turn into nearly 171 years!

Comment: just to clarify, it is acceptable to store only the value returned by `crypt()` - which contains the algorithm, the hash and the salt.

Comment: the thing about using sha1() is that it will only return characters [0-9a-f] whereas the CRYPT_BLOWFISH salt can use [0-9a-zA-Z./]. does that matter?